# Locating the first item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have this scenario:

```
>>> y=[[1]]
>>> y=y*2
>>> y
[[1], [1]]
>>> y[0].append(2)
>>> y
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

What I'd like to do is add the 2 into the first list within the outer list i.e. this is the desired output:

```
[[1, 2], [1]]
```

Comment: close it down then folks - thanks all for the references and answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing:

```
y=[[1]]
y=y*2
```

creates a list with two references to the same list object:

```
>>> y=[[1]]
>>> y=y*2
>>> id(y[0])  # The id of the first element...
28864920
>>> id(y[1])  # ...is the same as the id of the second.
28864920
>>>
```

This means that, when you modify one, the other will be affected as well.

---

To fix the problem, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
>>> y = [[1] for _ in xrange(2)]  # Use range here if you are on Python 3.x
>>> y
[[1], [1]]
>>> id(y[0])  # The id of the first element...
28864920
>>> id(y[1])  # ...is different from the id of the second.
28865520
>>> y[0].append(2)
>>> y
[[1, 2], [1]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace: **y=y*2** by **y.append([1])** to have different references.

Comment: Do not use append. iCodez has the correct approach by using list comprehensions.